# Use @PreDestroy annotation for logging server termination

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tomcat7

I'm using tomcat 7 and I want to log a new record in my database when my server is terminated (service tomcat stop).
I tried to use the `@PreDestroy` annotation - and I can see that the method annotated was invoked - but nothing is written in the database.
I guess it is since the connection to the database also gets terminated...

Is there a way for me to determine the order or the beans destruction? In that case I would like to determine my bean to be destroyed first.

Am I right?
Is there such a way?